# SwiftUI: .transition changes alignment in ZStack from center to top leading?

Tags: ios, swiftui

Using a GeometryReader inside of a ZStack, if a transition is specified, I'm seeing the content is aligned top-leading, but without a transition specified, the content is centered. Is this a bug in SwiftUI, or am I missing something? (I realize in this trivial example that there's never an actual transition that can occur, but I ran into this in a more complex scenario where a transition could occur.)

Here's the code:

```
public struct ContentView: View {
    public var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Text("Foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz")
                    .animation(.default)
                    .transition(.opacity)   // Without this line, the text is centered.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without the `.transition(.opacity)` line, the layout is:

[image]

With the `.transition(.opacity)` line, the layout is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`GeometryReader` is container where layout responsibility is on us, and its default behaviour might be unpredictable for different views. If you want predictable behaviour you should specify some explicit container, like below:

Variant 1:

```
ZStack(alignment: .center) {
  GeometryReader { proxy in
    VStack {
        Text("Foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz")
            .animation(.default)
            .transition(.opacity)
    }
  }
}
```

Variant 2:

```
  GeometryReader { proxy in
    ZStack(alignment: .center) {
        Text("Foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz")
            .animation(.default)
            .transition(.opacity)
    }
  }
```

I would prefer variant 2

Comment: Did you try these variants? I did try directly specifying the alignment explicitly but without luck.

Comment: @UberJason, yes, tested both with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry - I didn't see the VStack in the first variant. Thanks! Interesting thought about the default behavior. I see where you're coming from, but it's unclear to me why adding a transition would change that behavior, whatever the default is. That's unexpected to me.

Answer (score 0):

Why to use the GeometryReader without using provided GeometryProxy value?

```
import SwiftUI

public struct ContentView: View {
    public var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Text("Foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz")
                    .position(.init(x: proxy.size.width / 2, y: proxy.size.height / 2))
                    .animation(.default)
                    .transition(.opacity)   // The text is centered now.
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```